# Passing collection in querystring does not work with ODataQueryOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have following existing GET endpoint

```
  [HttpGet]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Section> oDataOptions) {
         //code here
         return response;     
    }
```

I need to add a collection in querystring like `<basequery>?$filter=id eq 1&includeCategory=A&includeCategory=B`

so this would be bound as a collection in modified get endpoint as follows -

```
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri (Name = "includeCategory"] ) List<Category> categories, ODataQueryOptions<Section> oDataOptions) {
       //code here
       return response;     
 }
```

Public enum Category {
A,
B
}

If I make postman request to this, I am getting `An item with the same key has already been added.`

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions..ctor(ODataQueryContext context, HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions`1..ctor(ODataQueryContext context, HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.OData.ODataQueryParameterBindingAttribute.ODataQueryParameterBinding.CreateODataQueryOptions[T](ODataQueryContext context, HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.OData.ODataQueryParameterBindingAttribute.ODataQueryParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

If my querystring has this `<basequery>?$filter=id eq 1&includeCategory=A`, this is working fine with ODataQueryOptions.

If my querystring has this `<basequery>?$filter=id eq 1&includeCategory[0]=A&includeCategory[0]=B`, this is working fine as well with ODataQueryOptions .

Same works for following with url `<basequery>/1?includeCategory=A&includeCategory=B` and endpoint with no $filter

```
 [Route("{id}")
 [HttpGet]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri (Name = "includeCategory"] ) List<Category> categories, long id) {
           //code here
           return response;     
     }
```

There is nothing in Section class that might collide with name Category.
That's why I am suspecting it's something to do with $filer, please suggest.

Comment: why can't you use the working URLs? What is the Category class definition? I couldn't reproduce your problem, sending `?$filter=id eq 1&includeCategory=A&includeCategory=B` works fine. Please, provide more information.

Comment: I ended up using indexing in the query like <basequery>?$filter=id eq 1&includeCategory[0]=A&includeCategory[0]=B. Category is an enum